# Prepared Statement with TS

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm having trouble with this syntax for sqlsrv driver.

This works just fine:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (Table1.Time >= {ts '2017-05-08
          00:00:00' } AND Table1.Time < {ts '2017-05-10 00:00:00' })";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

  $tbl = "<table>"
  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
      $tbl .= "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</td><td align=\"center\">".$row[2]."</td></tr>";
  }
  $tbl .= "</table>";
  echo $tbl;
```

But this doesn't work out all:

```
      $sql = "SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (Table1.Time >= {ts ? } AND Table1.Time < {ts ? })";
      $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, array('2017-05-08 00:00:00','2017-05-10 00:00:00'));
      $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
      $tbl = "<table>"
      while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
          $tbl .= "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</td><td align=\"center\">".$row[2]."</td></tr>";
      }
      $tbl .= "</table>";
      echo $tbl;
```

I get this error:

```
An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. )
```

Is there a proper way to pass date variables to the `{ ts ? }` statement?

Comment: When you get a blank page, enable the error logging in PHP. You should seperate UI from Database by using a tempate engine. Using parameter works different - remove {ts ?} and put only a ? in the postion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to get prepared statements working with [ODBC escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms712360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unlike MySQL (which has a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function) there are no functions built in to SQL Server that will convert to a Unix timestamp for you. You could [do the math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34455489/1255289) yourself, but maybe it's just easier to do it in PHP:

```
$begin = strtotime('2017-05-08 00:00:00');
$end = strtotime('2017-05-10 00:00:00');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Time >= ? AND Table1.Time < ?)";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array($begin, $end));
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
$tbl = "<table>"
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    $row[1] = $row[1]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $tbl .= "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td align=\"center\">$row[2]</td></tr>";
}
$tbl .= "</table>";
echo $tbl;
```

You should enumerate the columns that you're fetching instead of using `*` and then reference them by name (e.g. `$row["Time"]`) instead of number. It will make your code much more readable and protect it from changes in the database schema.

Comment: Actually, he can `format` sql server results in php if a column type is `datetime` or something like that and if it is returned as it is (I mean no cast or convertion). I don't know if there is any formal relation between sql server's `datetime` object and php's `DateTime` object but you can use it (maybe sqlsrv drivers do the tricks).

Comment: Well that's interesting, will edit the answer. There is no mention of that in the PHP documentation for any of the fetch methods. I did find this though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/default-php-data-types

Comment: pdo_sqlsrver seems to return a string, but sqlsrv seems to return a datetime object in php. I understand now. Thank you.