# How to convert date time to UNIX in PowerBI for Desktop

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am new to powerBI I want to convert `DateTime.LocalNow()` to UNIX Timestamp

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34455489/7740387) I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Duration.TotalSeconds

```
Duration.TotalSeconds(DateTime.LocalNow() - DateTime.FromText("1/1/1970"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```fs
let
    fun_DateTimeToUnix = (optional DateTime as nullable datetime) as number =>
        let
            default_DateTime = if DateTime is null then DateTime.From(DateTimeZone.UtcNow()) else DateTime,
            UnixDateTime = Duration.TotalSeconds(default_DateTime - DateTime.FromText("1/1/1970"))
        in
            UnixDateTime
in
    fun_DateTimeToUnix
```

As shown:

[image]

[image]