# How to convert a SQL Bignit column into Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: sql-server

How do I convert a sql bignit column in a table into days:hours:minutes:seconds

For example: (below) is the targeted column from the table and two rows of data:

```
        time_Left
        516542000
        604744000
```

How do I convert or Cast all the data in the column to display as Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds?

I've tried to convert it to datetime2, varchar, digit, decimals and datetime and I either get an error message or a string of digits. I'm looking for something to give me a break down of how many days:hours:minutes:Seconds the time_left is or hours:minutes:Seconds.

Comment: Without any details nobody can help you. What are those values? Why are you storing what seems to be something like dates as a bigint? What do you expect as output from the values you posted?

Comment: What does `516542000` represent? (0)0 seconds, 20 minutes, 54 hours and 516 days? Something else?

Comment: i'm guessing number of seconds since X

Comment: could be milliseconds too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this column contains seconds then you can do it as follows :

```
select time_left,
  CONCAT(
    FLOOR(time_left/(24*3600)),':',
    FLOOR(time_left%(24*3600)/3600),':', 
    FLOOR(time_left%(24*3600)%3600/60),':', 
    (time_left%(24*3600)%3600)%60 
) as "converted"
from mytable;
```

`FLOOR()` to return the largest integer value.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/X-sgfWuy)

Comment: Thank you I believe it is 'seconds' showing up in sql.                                                              In the application view, the 'Time_Left' column looks like (example) '5 Days 9 Hours 25 Minutes'.                                                                                                                                    A question I have is does the '5978' in the time life conversion =5978 days? In the demo you provided? That amount of days seems to be much larger then what it should be.

Comment: check the result using this formule : *Days*24*3600 + Hours*3600 + Minutes*60 + Seconds*  - example : `select 5978*24*3600 + 11*3600 + 53*60 + 20;`

Answer (score 0):

If they are unix timestamps they are seconds from 1/1/1970.

If so, then you can convert with `DATEADD(SECOND, 516542000, '1970-01-01')`.

Also refer to this [Convert Datetime to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455408/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp) for the reverse process.